# Postman - How can i loop through and verify if element is not null

Tags: loops, rest, postman, postman-testcase

this is my response body below and i want to ensure i am able to verify standardlabel and standardtext is not null. I know how to do it individually but, how can I do it through looping?
I have many of these and i want to ensure i can do it in one for loop as that would be a better way of doing it plus i do want the name of the standard label and standard text to be in the test.
This is individually:

```
pm.test("Verify " +  jsonData[13360][0].standardLabel + " and " + jsonData[13360][0].standardText +  " does not display null ", function () {
    pm.expect(jsonData[13360][0].standardLabel).to.exist
    pm.expect(jsonData[13360][0].standardLabel).to.not.be.null
    console.log(jsonData[13360][0].standardLabel)
        pm.expect(jsonData[13360][0].standardText).to.exist
    pm.expect(jsonData[13360][0].standardText).to.not.be.null
    console.log(jsonData[13360][0].standardText)
});
```

but I need to know how to do it with looping.

thanks

```
{
    "13360": [
        {
            "standardID": 13360,
            "standardTextID": 14698,
            "standardLabel": "APR.01.01.01",
            "standardText": "The hospital submits information to The Joint Commission as required.",
            "chapterID": 23,
            "chapterCode": "APR",
            "stdOrder": 162,
            "programID": 2,
            "epCount": 1,
            "ePsComplaint": 0,
            "finalScoreCompliance": "0 of 1 EPs Compliant",
            "ePsNotScored": 1,
            "percentCompliance": 0,
            "ePsNA": 0,
            "pmFlag": 0,
            "hcoid": 0,
            "isEstStandardFinding": null,
            "pmRedirectURL": "https://aqa.policymedical.net/policymed/api/tjcIntegration/list",
            "pmHost": "https://aqa.policymedical.net",
            "epTextID": 0
        }
    ],
    "13361": [
        {
            "standardID": 13361,
            "standardTextID": 14703,
            "standardLabel": "APR.01.02.01",
            "standardText": "The hospital provides accurate information throughout the accreditation process.",
            "chapterID": 23,
            "chapterCode": "APR",
            "stdOrder": 164,
            "programID": 2,
            "epCount": 1,
            "ePsComplaint": 0,
            "finalScoreCompliance": "0 of 1 EPs Compliant",
            "ePsNotScored": 1,
            "percentCompliance": 0,
            "ePsNA": 0,
            "pmFlag": 0,
            "hcoid": 0,
            "isEstStandardFinding": null,
            "pmRedirectURL": "https://aqa.policymedical.net/policymed/api/tjcIntegration/list",
            "pmHost": "https://aqa.policymedical.net",
            "epTextID": 0
        }
    ],
    "13362": [
        {
            "standardID": 13362,
            "standardTextID": 14371,
            "standardLabel": "APR.01.03.01",
            "standardText": "The hospital reports any changes in the information provided in the application for accreditation and any changes made between surveys.",
            "chapterID": 23,
            "chapterCode": "APR",
            "stdOrder": 166,
            "programID": 2,
            "epCount": 2,
            "ePsComplaint": 0,
            "finalScoreCompliance": "0 of 2 EPs Compliant",
            "ePsNotScored": 2,
            "percentCompliance": 0,
            "ePsNA": 0,
            "pmFlag": 0,
            "hcoid": 0,
            "isEstStandardFinding": null,
            "pmRedirectURL": "https://aqa.policymedical.net/policymed/api/tjcIntegration/list",
            "pmHost": "https://aqa.policymedical.net",
            "epTextID": 0
        }
    ],
    "13363": [
        {
            "standardID": 13363,
            "standardTextID": 14708,
            "standardLabel": "APR.02.01.01",
            "standardText": "The hospital permits the performance of a survey at The Joint Commission's discretion.",
            "chapterID": 23,
            "chapterCode": "APR",
            "stdOrder": 168,
            "programID": 2,
            "epCount": 1,
            "ePsComplaint": 0,
            "finalScoreCompliance": "0 of 1 EPs Compliant",
            "ePsNotScored": 1,
            "percentCompliance": 0,
            "ePsNA": 0,
            "pmFlag": 0,
            "hcoid": 0,
            "isEstStandardFinding": null,
            "pmRedirectURL": "https://aqa.policymedical.net/policymed/api/tjcIntegration/list",
            "pmHost": "https://aqa.policymedical.net",
            "epTextID": 0
        }
    ],
    "13376": [
        {
            "standardID": 13376,
            "standardTextID": 30579,
            "standardLabel": "APR.04.01.01",
            "standardText": "The hospital selects and uses performance measures from among those available that are relevant to the services it provides and the population(s) it serves to meet specified ORYX® measure reporting requirements for accreditation.\nNote: Hospitals are encouraged to keep up-to-date on any changes in the ORYX® requirements by reviewing recent issues of The Joint Commission Perspectives® or by going to the “Measurement” area on The Joint Commission website at http://www.jointcommission.org.",
            "chapterID": 23,
            "chapterCode": "APR",
            "stdOrder": 172,
            "programID": 2,
            "epCount": 14,
            "ePsComplaint": 0,
            "finalScoreCompliance": "0 of 14 EPs Compliant",
            "ePsNotScored": 14,
            "percentCompliance": 0,
            "ePsNA": 0,
            "pmFlag": 0,
            "hcoid": 0,
            "isEstStandardFinding": null,
            "pmRedirectURL": "https://aqa.policymedical.net/policymed/api/tjcIntegration/list",
            "pmHost": "https://aqa.policymedical.net",
            "epTextID": 0
        }
    ],
    "13365": [
        {
            "standardID": 13365,
            "standardTextID": 14716,
            "standardLabel": "APR.05.01.01",
            "standardText": "The hospital allows The Joint Commission to review the results of external evaluations from publicly recognized bodies.",
            "chapterID": 23,
            "chapterCode": "APR",
            "stdOrder": 174,
            "programID": 2,
            "epCount": 1,
            "ePsComplaint": 0,
            "finalScoreCompliance": "0 of 1 EPs Compliant",
            "ePsNotScored": 1,
            "percentCompliance": 0,
            "ePsNA": 0,
            "pmFlag": 0,
            "hcoid": 0,
            "isEstStandardFinding": null,
            "pmRedirectURL": "https://aqa.policymedical.net/policymed/api/tjcIntegration/list",
            "pmHost": "https://aqa.policymedical.net",
            "epTextID": 0
        }
    ],
    "13366": [
        {
            "standardID": 13366,
            "standardTextID": 14377,
            "standardLabel": "APR.06.01.01",
            "standardText": "Applicants and accredited hospitals do not use Joint Commission employees to provide accreditation-related consulting services.",
            "chapterID": 23,
            "chapterCode": "APR",
            "stdOrder": 176,
            "programID": 2,
            "epCount": 1,
            "ePsComplaint": 0,
            "finalScoreCompliance": "0 of 1 EPs Compliant",
            "ePsNotScored": 1,
            "percentCompliance": 0,
            "ePsNA": 0,
            "pmFlag": 0,
            "hcoid": 0,
            "isEstStandardFinding": null,
            "pmRedirectURL": "https://aqa.policymedical.net/policymed/api/tjcIntegration/list",
            "pmHost": "https://aqa.policymedical.net",
            "epTextID": 0
        }
    ],
    "13367": [
        {
            "standardID": 13367,
            "standardTextID": 14721,
            "standardLabel": "APR.07.01.01",
            "standardText": "The hospital accepts the presence of Joint Commission surveyor management staff or a Board of Commissioners member in the role of observer of an on-site survey.",
            "chapterID": 23,
            "chapterCode": "APR",
            "stdOrder": 178,
            "programID": 2,
            "epCount": 1,
            "ePsComplaint": 0,
            "finalScoreCompliance": "0 of 1 EPs Compliant",
            "ePsNotScored": 1,
            "percentCompliance": 0,
            "ePsNA": 0,
            "pmFlag": 0,
            "hcoid": 0,
            "isEstStandardFinding": null,
            "pmRedirectURL": "https://aqa.policymedical.net/policymed/api/tjcIntegration/list",
            "pmHost": "https://aqa.policymedical.net",
            "epTextID": 0
        }
    ],
    "13368": [
        {
            "standardID": 13368,
            "standardTextID": 14382,
            "standardLabel": "APR.08.01.01",
            "standardText": "The hospital accurately represents its accreditation status and the programs and services to which Joint Commission accreditation applies.",
            "chapterID": 23,
            "chapterCode": "APR",
            "stdOrder": 180,
            "programID": 2,
            "epCount": 2,
            "ePsComplaint": 0,
            "finalScoreCompliance": "0 of 2 EPs Compliant",
            "ePsNotScored": 2,
            "percentCompliance": 0,
            "ePsNA": 0,
            "pmFlag": 0,
            "hcoid": 0,
            "isEstStandardFinding": null,
            "pmRedirectURL": "https://aqa.policymedical.net/policymed/api/tjcIntegration/list",
            "pmHost": "https://aqa.policymedical.net",
            "epTextID": 0
        }
    ],
    "13369": [
        {
            "standardID": 13369,
            "standardTextID": 16764,
            "standardLabel": "APR.09.01.01",
            "standardText": "The hospital notifies the public it serves about how to contact its hospital management and The Joint Commission to report concerns about patient safety and quality of care.\r\nNote: Methods of notice may include, but are not limited to, distribution of information about The Joint Commission, including contact information in published materials such as brochures and/or posting this information on the hospital's website.",
            "chapterID": 23,
            "chapterCode": "APR",
            "stdOrder": 182,
            "programID": 2,
            "epCount": 2,
            "ePsComplaint": 0,
            "finalScoreCompliance": "0 of 2 EPs Compliant",
            "ePsNotScored": 2,
            "percentCompliance": 0,
            "ePsNA": 0,
            "pmFlag": 0,
            "hcoid": 0,
            "isEstStandardFinding": null,
            "pmRedirectURL": "https://aqa.policymedical.net/policymed/api/tjcIntegration/list",
            "pmHost": "https://aqa.policymedical.net",
            "epTextID": 0
        }
    ],
    "13370": [
        {
            "standardID": 13370,
            "standardTextID": 14726,
            "standardLabel": "APR.09.02.01",
            "standardText": "Any individual who provides care, treatment, and services can report concerns about safety or the quality of care to The Joint Commission without retaliatory action from the hospital.",
            "chapterID": 23,
            "chapterCode": "APR",
            "stdOrder": 184,
            "programID": 2,
            "epCount": 3,
            "ePsComplaint": 0,
            "finalScoreCompliance": "0 of 3 EPs Compliant",
            "ePsNotScored": 3,
            "percentCompliance": 0,
            "ePsNA": 0,
            "pmFlag": 0,
            "hcoid": 0,
            "isEstStandardFinding": null,
            "pmRedirectURL": "https://aqa.policymedical.net/policymed/api/tjcIntegration/list",
            "pmHost": "https://aqa.policymedical.net",
            "epTextID": 0
        }
    ],
    "13371": [
        {
            "standardID": 13371,
            "standardTextID": 14731,
            "standardLabel": "APR.09.03.01",
            "standardText": "The hospital is truthful and accurate when describing information in its Quality Report to the public.",
            "chapterID": 23,
            "chapterCode": "APR",
            "stdOrder": 186,
            "programID": 2,
            "epCount": 1,
            "ePsComplaint": 0,
            "finalScoreCompliance": "0 of 1 EPs Compliant",
            "ePsNotScored": 1,
            "percentCompliance": 0,
            "ePsNA": 0,
            "pmFlag": 0,
            "hcoid": 0,
            "isEstStandardFinding": null,
            "pmRedirectURL": "https://aqa.policymedical.net/policymed/api/tjcIntegration/list",
            "pmHost": "https://aqa.policymedical.net",
            "epTextID": 0
        }
    ],
    "14227": [
        {
            "standardID": 14227,
            "standardTextID": 30501,
            "standardLabel": "APR.09.04.01",
            "standardText": "The hospital provides care, treatment, services, and an environment that pose no risk of an “Immediate Threat to Health or Safety.”",
            "chapterID": 23,
            "chapterCode": "APR",
            "stdOrder": 188,
            "programID": 2,
            "epCount": 1,
            "ePsComplaint": 0,
            "finalScoreCompliance": "0 of 1 EPs Compliant",
            "ePsNotScored": 1,
            "percentCompliance": 0,
            "ePsNA": 0,
            "pmFlag": 0,
            "hcoid": 0,
            "isEstStandardFinding": null,
            "pmRedirectURL": "https://aqa.policymedical.net/policymed/api/tjcIntegration/list",
            "pmHost": "https://aqa.policymedical.net",
            "epTextID": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i figured out the answer --> 

var jsonData = pm.response.json();
data = ["13360","13361","13362","13363", "13376", "13365", "13366", "13367", "13368", "13369", "13370", "13371", "14227"];
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    pm.test("Verify " +  jsonData[data[i]][0].standardLabel + " and " + jsonData[data[i]][0].standardText +  " does not display null ", function () {
console.log(jsonData[data[i]][0].standardLabel)
console.log(jsonData[data[i]][0].standardText)
pm.expect(jsonData[data[i]][0].standardLabel).to.exist
pm.expect(jsonData[data[i]][0].standardLabel).to.not.be.null
pm.expect(jsonData[data[i]][0].standardText).to.exist
pm.expect(jsonData[data[i]][0].standardText).to.not.be.null
})
}
```